# Primitive type conversion in assembly

Tags: assembly, type-conversion

I'm currently learning some basics of assembly code. I'm reading a book where some exercises are proposed. I don't understand the answer of one of them.

[Here](http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=576040Assemblyconversion.jpg) are the exercises with the answers of the book. I'm in trouble with lines 3 and 4.

At line 3, we must convert a **char to an unsigned**. First I do the conversion : *char --> unsigned char*. No change in bits level. Then *unsigned char --> unsigned* so I use zero extension. This would lead to the instruction **movzbl %al, (%edx)**

At line 4 we must convert a **unsigned char to an int**. First I do the conversion : *unsigned char --> char*. Not change in bits level. Then *char --> int* where I do a sign extension. This would lead to the instruction **movsbl %al, (%edx)**

Am I doing something wrong or do you think this is an error from the book ?

Thank you !

Comment: Looks like that table has some typos in it. For example, it suggests on one line that you should use a `movzdl` instruction, which to my knowledge doesn't even exist (though I've rarely used AT&T syntax).

Comment: My bad ;) It's 'movzbl'.

Comment: I meant in the table you linked to. Or did you create that one yourself?

Comment: I completed the column "instructions" from row 2 to 7 (the goal of the exercise is to complete this column). But these answers correspond to the solution in the book (I did a mistake and wrote "movzdl" instead of "movzbl".)